# Loading a custom font into React Native Webview on Android

Tags: react-native, fonts

I am using [react-native-dynamic-fonts](https://github.com/eVisit/react-native-dynamic-fonts) to inject dynamic fonts at run time.

I downloaded [Spicy Rice](https://fonts.google.com/?selection.family=Spicy+Rice) from Google Fonts and I am using it like so:

```
export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  componentWillMount() {
    loadFonts([{name: 'SpicyRice-Regular', data: font, type: 'ttf'}], true).then(function(names) {
      console.log('Loaded all fonts successfully. Font names are: ', names);
  });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, marginTop: 150}}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'SpicyRice-Regular', fontSize: 25, color: 'red'}}>Foo</Text>
        <WebView style={{ flex: 1, }} source={content} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I see my console log and it returns `SpicyRice-Regular`. However, when I try to use it in my WebView on Android, it doesn't seem to work.

My WebView simply uses:

```
p {
    font-size: 150px;
    font-family: 'SpicyRice-Regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
  }
```

However, it renders on iOS but doesn't on Android.

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Font's don't waterfall through for Android Webview. Just like the Chrome browser, each instance of a Webview is sandboxed into its own environment.

You do have access to the filesystem though and you can to link directly to the font asset using `url("file:///android_asset/fonts/<filename>")` in the Webview CSS properties so something like this should work:

```
p {
    font-size: 150px;
    font-family: 'SpicyRice-Regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/SpicyRice-Regular.ttf')
  }
```